# How to create union of <svg:text> using command line?

Tags: xslt, command-line, svg

I'm currently using `Inkscape` but the so-called command-line mode is really slow as they require –most of the time– the GUI.

### Current Code

```
  inkscape -f input.svg  --select=hanzi --select=pinyin --verb=SelectionUnion
```

Creating a single union and save the file this way took ~2s (after [reducing fonts list](https://gist.github.com/su-v/0a6080f5467184b84888#file-fonts-conf)). I need to [repeat this operation 20k times](https://github.com/edouard-lopez/Hanzi-Pinyin-Font/blob/98a7fe3d7dbf0a5e492658feec28e6a513a89b17/bin/svg-text2svg-font.bash) and it took me ~12h to accomplish.

So I'm looking for an alternative solution to create this union.

### Resources

I created a gist to show input/ouput file: [Hanzi Pinyin Font from multiple  elements to a single  (Union path operations)](https://gist.github.com/edouard-lopez/6494377)

### Question

How do you recommend doing this either using a `CLI` tools or writing an `XSLT` sheet? Is it even doable with XSLT?

Comment: Can you post a sample of the XML input and the corresponding output you want? That way people familiar with XSLT but not familiar with Inkscape might be able to tell whether XSLT helps.

Comment: I updated the description, see the **Resources** section

Answer (score 1):

This is not an XML transform you're doing, what you're actually doing is taking some text e.g. ABC and converting that to a path which draws out the letters A, B and C as lines and arcs.

You'd need to use something which can understand the fonts you're using and how they are rendered in order to do that and as fonts aren't in XML format, you can't use XSLT to do it.

Comment: I can't for the vectorization process of each `<svg:text>` but I can for merging of two svg:path/@d into one. And I reckon I can call external code (e.g. Java class) from an `XSL`

Comment: That sounds like using a hammer to knock in a screw.

Comment: Are you talking about java?